# How to write this conversion algorithm

Tags: statistics, algorithms

I have to calculate Grade Average from the scale of 1 to 5 such that 1 being the best (100%) and 5 being the worst (0%). So we have,

```
1 = 100% (Best)
2 = 75%
3 = 50%
4 = 25%
5 = 0% (Worst)
```

For a given subject, the student scored 40 out of 100. So we have 40%.

Now how do I convert the 40% into the scale of 1 to 5. I know it must be between 4 (25%) and 3 (50%).

Would it be 3.some decimal (3.3) or 4.some decimal (4.3)? I mean, should I travel with the decimals upwards from the 3 or 4?

I am making a formula in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A score of $40\%$ would give a grade of $3.4$. In general, a score of $x\%$ corresponds to the grade $5 - \frac{x}{25}$.

Answer (score 1):

How about $g= 125 - 25s$, where $g$ is the percentage score and $s$ is your scale 1-5.?  In this event, 
$$s = {125 -g \over 25},$$
so if $g = 40$, $s = 85/25 = 3.4$.